# When storageclass is deleted in kubernetes, pv still has storageclass information

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pvc

Storageclass was deleted with 'kubectl delete storageclass'.
But pv still has the deleted storageclass information.(kubectl get pv)
There is no problem with the pods being recreated.
Can someone please explain this situation?

Answer (score 0):

This can be explain in two ways :

If your PVC information is not deleted then If you want to reuse the same storage asset, create a new PersistentVolume with the same storage asset definition.For more information go through this [doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/).

If you want to delete PVC information also then you need to use CSI Plugins which delete the information PVC along with the storage class. Then you can create the new Pods with new storage. For this more information go through this [doc](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/75448)